# rails unable to access a value in the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a params hash that looks like this:

```
puts contact_params
=> {"classifiable_classification_codes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"5", "relateds_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"classifiable_id"=>"6", "id"=>"15"}}}}}
```

So I expect when I do this contact_params["classifiable_classification_codes_attributes"], I subsequently get {"0"=>{"id"=>"5"...

In fact, that is exactly what happens in the console:

```
> contact_params["classifiable_classification_codes_attributes"]
 => {"0"=>{"id"=>"5", "relateds_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"classifiable_id"=>"6", "id"=>"15"}}}}
```

However, in the controller when I try do this, it returns a nil value, as if classifiable_classification_codes_attributes is not a key. I also tried the symbol form :classifiable_classification_codes_attributes. But neither of them return any results.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this might be a Strong Parameters issue in which case you need to add something like

```
private
def my_params
  params.require(:classifiable_classification_codes_attributes).permit(: id, :relateds_attributes)
end
```

Read more at: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Even after doing   params.require(:contact).permit(: classifiable_classification_codes_attributes ,:id, :relateds_attributes), I still cannot retrieve the value.

Comment: Can you post your controller in the original question?

Comment: and since you're using Strings the params.require should use Strings as well, my mistake just used to always using symbols.

Comment: How stupid I am. I was trying to access it with classifiable_classification_code_attributes rather than classifiable_classification_codes_attributes. I forgot to add the s at the end.